# Custom function in Esqueleto "where_" cluase

Tags: database, haskell, monads, esqueleto

I'd like to write a function that checks if user's login and hashed password exists in database. Let's assume DB is very simple:

```hs
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
    User
        login String
        passHash Hash
        UniqueL login
        deriving Eq Show
```

Where `Hash` is an alias `type Hash = PasswordHash PBKDF2` from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/password-2.0.1.1/docs/Data-Password-PBKDF2.html.

Also, for simplicity let's assume that both login and password are passed to my function as `String`.

There's a function in the module called `checkPassword` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/password-2.0.1.1/docs/Data-Password-PBKDF2.html#g:3) that checks if a password produces the required hash. However, I don't know how can I use it in esqualeto `where_` clause.

I came up with something like this:

```hs
type DB m a = ReaderT SqlBackend m a

checkCredentials ::(MonadIO m, MonadLogger m) => (String, String) -> DB m Bool
checkCredentials (login, password) = do
    let hashFunc = (checkPassword $ mkPassword (pack password))
    res <- 
        select $ 
            from $ \user -> do 
                -- This won't wwork
                where_ (user ^. UserLogin ==. val login &&. hashFunc (user ^. UserPassHash) ==. val PasswordCheckSuccess)
                return user
    return (negate $ null res)
```

but the part `hashFunc (user ^. UserPassHash)` obviously won't work. I guess I need to enter with my `hashFunc` into a monad (or two), but I have no idea how to do this.

I noticed that `UserPassHash` is of type `EntityField User Hash`. I wonder how can I turn it into `EntityField User PasswordCheck`.

Comment: The problem is that `where_` will convert to an SQL expression, so you can not use arbitrary functions here, since the SQL backend would not understand this. Often the credentials are checked at the application level, so you fetch the user with the username, and then check if the hashed password matches the given one.

Comment: I see. This makes sense. So the best way is to try getting a user by login (as in my snippet - into the "res" value) and then checking the password hash on application side (i.e. outside of the SQL query), right ?

If so - @WillemVanOnsem can you post an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: Uhm, the code above looks weird. It looks like you are trying to hash the hashed password, which is wrong. If your password hashes are not "salted", then you could write the correct query `... &&. user ^. UserPassHash ==. hash password` (for some proper `hash` function) which would work because the hash is computed by Haskell, and its result is then injected as a constant in the formed SQL query (no need for SQL to know the `hash` function ). If the passwords are salted (as they should, for security) then you need to follow Willem's advice and extract the salt+hash, then check it in Haskell.

Comment: In any case, even if there is no "salt", Willem's advice will work.

Comment: Long story short: The library takes care of salt itself. For details you can check the doc link I provided for checkPassword function.